# jQuery not working on AJAX-loaded content to show/hide div contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a project where I need to show/hide a div according to a drop down value. Show/hide works fine when it performs on same page but when I try this same in an AJAX-loaded function it fails.

I hope there is something that is missing that I don't know.

In short, I want to hide/show the div when I select option on an AJAX-loaded page.

**index.php**:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <!-- there is nothing related to it... it's here because I have copied it from the w3schools website -->
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a person:</option>
            <option value="1">getdata</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br><br><br>
    <div id="txtHint" style="background-color: #CCCCCC"><b> ajax data will listed here</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**getdata.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> its page2</p>
    <select name="type" id="type" >
        <option value="1show" >show div 1</option>
        <option value="2show" >show div 1 </option>
    </select>

    <div id="div1" style="display:none">
        div1 data
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:none">
        div 2 data 
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$('#type').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value == '1show' ) {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
    } else if(this.value == '2show') {
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: use $(document).on("change","#type", function() {     });

Comment: Ajax content is not in the dom structure.. So by directly calling it you will not find the things you are looking for, itsb etter to start searching from an already existing parent element...

Comment: i have no idea what you are doing. but you maybe wanna take a look at jquery's own ajax-function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: ajax fetch works fine.  and i copied it from W3schools site which i mentioned in index.php page sir @Naruto

Comment: simply i just want show/hide div in ajax loaded page sir @low_rents

Comment: maam its not working @DharaParmar

Comment: if you are already using jquery, then use jquery's ajax-function like I mentioned in my first comment. and simplify your code - what you have posted is a huge mess!

Comment: sorry for that sir will do it after finding solution of this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the event to the document.

try

```
$(document).on('change','#type' ,function() {
    if ( this.value == '1show' ) {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
    } else if(this.value == '2show') {
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: i just load both files separately using ajax 1-data file and 2-js file and in js file  i have used your code $(document).on('change','#type' ,function() {
now it working.and because in my ajax i used to load innerHTML so it loads only HTML not js thats what i think

Answer (score 0):

may be ajax of INDEX.php loads only html data. so i create another file which contains all the scripts and that works fine. still waiting for any expert to explain why that happen.

this contains js data
this is how i call js file in index page after first ajax is called
     $("#box").load("ab.js");